# Creating an xlsx sheet in R - font colour not working

Tags: r, xlsx

I am working on a project where I need to automate the production of spreadsheets of data from a particular type of data-frame.  I have read a useful explanation of how to do this [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r#create-and-format-a-nice-excel-workbook), and based on this explanation, I have created some code in `R.Studio` (professional version 1.1.383) using the `xlsx` package (version 0.5.7).  My code generates a spreadsheet of data from an existing data frame `TABLE`.  Here is the code I am using, with a mock data frame used to create a reproducible example:

```
#In this code we create a mock data frame called TABLE
#In practice we have a larger data frame with data that is not reproduced here

TABLE <- data.frame(Var1 = c(1, 6, 3, 9, 10, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2), 
                    Var2 = c(18.1, 14.2, 12.0, 21.3, 33.4, 16.0, 15.4, 8.6, 6.7, 12.9),
                    Var3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));

#Create workbook, sheet, columns and styles
WB             <- createWorkbook(type = "xlsx");
SHEET          <- createSheet(WB, sheetName = "My Data");

rows           <- createRow(SHEET, rowIndex = 1:5);
cells          <- createCell(rows, colIndex = 1:(1+ncol(TABLE)));

STYLE_TITLE    <- CellStyle(WB) + 
                  Font(WB, name = "Calibri", heightInPoints = 16, 
                       color = "black", isBold = TRUE, isItalic = FALSE);

#Add data from data frame TABLE
addDataFrame(TABLE, SHEET, startRow = 4L, startColumn = 2L, 
             colnamesStyle = STYLE_COLNAMES, row.names = FALSE);

#Add title
setCellValue(cells[[2, 2]], "This is my spreadsheet title"); 
setCellStyle(cells[[2, 2]], STYLE_TITLE);

#Save workbook
saveWorkbook(WB, "My Pretty Workbook.xlsx");
```

This code successfully generates the spreadsheet I want, and everything looks how I want it, except that **the title comes up in white font**, which means they can't be seen on the white background of the spreadsheet.  This seems to me to be contrary to the part of my code where I specify the `Font` with `color = "black"`.  I have also tried using `color = "#000000"` and this gets the same result.

Why is my title and information text coming up in white font?  How do I fix this?

Comment: If you're willing to experiment with a different package, my favorite is `openxlsx` - I don't often need formatting, but I think it's one of the strengths of this package  (see https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/f/inst/doc/formatting.pdf)

Comment: I agree with @MelissaKey. Although I provided a workaround in `xlsx`, I find `openxlsx` easier to use and more intuitive for complex formatting. It also avoids the java dependence that comes with `xlsx`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you type `STYLE_TITLE` in the console, you can see in the output (look under `$font$ref`), that the color is being set to `FFFFFF`, which is white. Below is what I see in the console (I've shown only the relevant portion of the output). Note the `FFFFFF` on the last line:

```
STYLE_TITLE    <- STYLE_TITLE    <- CellStyle(WB) + 
  Font(WB, name = "Calibri", heightInPoints = 16, 
       color = "black", isBold = TRUE, isItalic = FALSE)

STYLE_TITLE
```

> ```
> $font
> $ref
> [1] "Java-Object{<xml-fragment xmlns:main=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org
> /spreadsheetml/2006/main\">\n  <main:name val=\"Calibri\"/>\n  <main:sz val=\"16.0
> \"/>\n  <main:color rgb=\"FFFFFF\"/>\n  <main:b val=\"true\"/>\n</xml-fragment>}"
> ```

I don't know why this is occurring or how to get the `Font` function to convert "black" or "#000000" into the proper color code of `000000`. However, I did find (strangely) that other color encodings work properly. For example, you can use the color `"#010101"`, which is almost black:

```
STYLE_TITLE    <- STYLE_TITLE    <- CellStyle(WB) + 
  Font(WB, name = "Calibri", heightInPoints = 16, 
       color = "#010101", isBold = TRUE, isItalic = FALSE)

STYLE_TITLE
```

> ```
> $font
> $ref
> [1] "Java-Object{<xml-fragment xmlns:main=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\">\n
> <main:name val=\"Calibri\"/>\n  <main:sz val=\"16.0\"/>\n  <main:color
> rgb=\"010101\"/>\n  <main:b val=\"true\"/>\n</xml-fragment>}"
> ```

This and other color names and rgb color specifications (e.g., "red", "purple", "#F372B6") are also encoded properly in the `Font` output object, and the colors are rendered as expected in the spreadsheet output.

I know you wanted 100% black, but if you can settle for 99.6% black, this workaround should get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and solved using color = "000000" instead color = "#000000".

However, as eipi10 said, other colors works with the "#" encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Black and white are just mixed up. Therefore, if you want a white text color, use color = "black" and vice versa for black text use color = "white".