# How can I make white text in vector graphics in R?

Tags: r, vector-graphics

I'm trying to make vector graphics that can be inserted into Word.  Whenever I try to use white text, though, it shows up as black when I insert it into a Word document.  If I output to PDF, it works fine, but unfortunately I can't import PDFs into Word directly.  How can I get white text to stay white when I output to EMF and import that EMF image to a Word Document?

```
library(devEMF)
library(grid)

emf("test.emf",height=3,width=3)
  grid.newpage()
  grid.circle(x=0.5,y=0.5,r=0.1,gp=gpar(col=NA,fill="blue"))
  grid.text(1,x=0.5,y=0.5,gp=gpar(col="white"))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate this in a Word document directly by creating it in `rmarkdown`:

````
---
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(grid)
```

```{r}
grid.circle(x=0.5, y=0.5, r=0.1, gp=gpar(col=NA,fill="blue"))
grid.text(1, x=0.5, y=0.5, gp=gpar(col="white"))
```
````

The output looked as expected when I tried this on my system.

[image]

However, when I generated an EMF file using your code directly and dragged `test.emf` into a Word file, I got the same result you did:

[image]

I did find, however, that if I changed the color to `"#FEFEFE"`, which is virtually white, then the color rendered correctly in the EMF file output (as did any other color specification I tried, except for `"white"` or `"#FFFFFF"`). So if you need to save as an EMF, this will hopefully get the job done.

A few months ago, I [answered an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50960527/496488) with a similar issue. In that case, the goal was to write an xlsx file using the `xlsx` package and have the worksheet title in black text. However, the text was actually rendered as white text in the output file. In that case, changing the color setting to `"#010101"`, which is virtually black, worked, as did any other color specification except pure black (`"#000000"` or `"black"`). I don't know if the two issues are related, but I thought I'd mention it in case they are.

Answer (score 3):

(note I am the developer of the devEMF package; I only occasionally check stackoverflow, so just seeing this now)

devEMF contained a bug that neglected to set the text color for white text until non-white text had been used first.  I have submitted to CRAN devEMF version 3.6-2 which fixes this bug; it will take a few days to percolate through CRAN.  Meanwhile, since your use case is Microsoft Word, which handles EMF+ well, you can work around the problem immediately by requesting EMF+ fonts when you open the device:

`emf("test.emf",height=3,width=3, emfPlusFont=TRUE)`